# Convert string to RenderFragment

Tags: blazor

I'm wondering if there's a recommended way of converting string to RenderFragment in code.
Now I'm doing this:

```
RenderFragment fragm = @<text>@myString</text>;
```

but I don't know if this is the best way to do it

Comment: You might read about the [wig-pig syntax](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-placeholders-to-renderfragments/) (down the page...) `@:@{place some code here}`;

Comment: That is a decent way to create a RenderFragment, but why? You can use the string anywhere you use the fragment - there is no benefit I can see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "recommended" method that I know of.

A `RenderFragment` is a delegate defined as:

```
public delegate void RenderFragment(RenderTreeBuilder builder);
```

It's a block of code passed to the `Renderer` to actually render the component markup.

Here's a demo page that shows three ways to define one:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="p-2">
    @RF1
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    @RF2
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    @RF3
</div>

@code {
    //need to be careful with the builder name not to clash with one the names used by the Razor compiler
    private RenderFragment RF1 => (mybuilder) =>
        {
        <text>@myString</text>
        };

    private RenderFragment RF2 => (builder) =>
        {
            builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"<text>{myString}</text>");
        };

    // DO NOT use an loop incrementer for the sequence number
    private RenderFragment RF3 => (builder) =>
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "text");
            builder.AddContent(1, myString);
            builder.CloseElement();
        };

    private string myString = "Hello Blazor";
}
```

The first one is a little counterintuitive.  It only works in a Razor component file because the Razor compiler recognises it and compiles it into a code block similar to the second example.